# Does stat_function() in ggplot2 work with args other than vectors?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to print some values (geom_point) and on top of that draw some function (stat_function) with `ggplot2`, however I can't plot the function because it has an argument of type list.

I want to print the function `create.new.func(x,W)` which gets two parameters (x,W) where x is a numeric value and W a list containing two matrices of different dimensions. I tried using the line

```
stat_function(fun= create.new.func,aes(colour="sep1"),args = list(W=superW))
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

> ```
> Computation failed in `stat_function()`: non-conformable arguments##
> ```

Of course `create.new.func(x,W=superW)` works perfectly for any x.
All the code snippet I have seen so far seem to use only vectors for the args parameter, hence my question.

Example:

```
W <- list(matrix(c(1, -1, -1, 1), nrow = 2), matrix(c(1, 2)))

func <- function(x, W){
    sum(W[[2]] * (W[[1]] %*% c(1, x)))
}

ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(x = 0, y = 0)) + 
    theme_bw()+
    stat_function(fun = func, args = list(W), aes(colour = "black")) +
    scale_colour_manual("data", values = c("blue"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per `?stat_function`, `fun` must be vectorized. `stat_function` makes a vector of x values of length `n` (101 by default) between the range of x values, passes it into the function, and plots the created x values with the resulting y values. For instance,

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + stat_function(aes(x = 0:1), fun = sqrt)
```

[image]

Note that `x` must have a range; if `x = 0`, the result will just be a point, even though `stat_function` will still make a vector of x values (that will all be the same), i.e. `seq(0, 0, length.out = 101)`.

A quick way to get your code working, then, is to add a useful domain for `x` and iterate over `x` in `func`:

```r
W <- list(matrix(c(1, -1, -1, 1), nrow = 2), matrix(c(1, 2)))

func <- function(x, W){
    sapply(x, function(x_i){
        sum(W[[2]] * (W[[1]] %*% c(1, x_i)))
    })
}

# it's vectorized now
func(1:10, W)
#> [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(x = 0, y = 0)) + 
    stat_function(aes(x = 0:1), fun = func, args = list(W = W))
```

[image]

Ultimately this is not a *great* way to vectorize `func` because it just loops instead of writing better code/math, so it is not terribly efficient. In this case, 101 iterations of a simple function will still be very fast, though, so it's not necessarily worth the effort of optimizing it further. For slower, more complicated functions, it may be.

Comment: Thank for your amazing answer! I used "stat_function(aes(x = 0:1), fun = function(x,W) sapply(x, function(x) func(x,W)), args = list(W = W))" so I didn't need to modify my original function.

Comment: I don't know if related but if you define "x" before the stat_function, then its resulting domain will be the addition of both domains. Example: "df <- data.frame(x=seq(-2,2,.01),y=sqrt(abs(seq(-2,2,.01))))
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=df,aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  stat_function(aes(x = 0:1), fun = function(x,W) sapply(x, function(x) func(x,W)), args = list(W = W))" Domain for stat_function is (-2,2) and not (0,1). Now this is not a problem right now, I just wonder if there is some way to restrict the domain to the last specification.

Comment: Yep, it uses the limits of the plot by default, so if different layers have different domains, it uses a maximal one. You can restrict it to an explicit interval with the `xlim` parameter.

Comment: OK. Then if I have some plot and want to restrict a function to a narrower interval, then maybe it's best to use something like "annotate" and enter the vectors manually, no?

Comment: If it's straight lines, sure. That's not really the intended purpose of `stat_function`, which is how ggplot reproduces the functionality of `curve`. If you still want to use `stat_function`, just set `xlim`.